# Redis LRU-Eviction, Evicted Item Persistance

Tags: redis

I am new to redis, So please bear with me. Lets say I have configured a redis to have a `maxmemory` of **50mb**, and I set eviction policy to `allkeys-lru`. And then I keep inserting and querying data. When the process memory gets to 50mb it starts to evict least recently used items.

My questions is do the evicted items persist on disk or are they lost for ever ? I mean if I do a `GET` for an evicted key, what do I get. Does redis fetch it from disk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evicted is gone. With redis, nothing is on disk that isn't also in memory. (Technically, there will still probably be traces of it for some time, but that's just implementation details. As far as the data model is concerned, it's been deleted, and a GET won't find it.)